# How to get specific sheet by id in Google Apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I want to define a specific sheet as an id value using the `getSheetById()` function.

It is said that `getSheetId()` is undefined and does not work.

The code I used is as follows.

```
function getSheetById(gid){
  for (var sheet in SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()) {
    if(sheet.getSheetId() == gid){
      return sheet;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the Sheet object by giving the sheet ID.

When I saw your script, in the case of `for (var sheet in SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()) {}`, `sheet` is index. I thought that this is the reason of your issue. In this case, how about using "for...of" as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getSheetById(gid){
  for (var sheet of SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()) {
    if(sheet.getSheetId() == gid){
      return sheet;
    }
  }
}
```

Or, I thought that in this case, `find` might be able to be also used as follows.

```js
function getSheetById(gid) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().find(s => s.getSheetId() == gid);
}
```

- When the valid `gid` is given to the function `getSheetById`, the Sheet object is returned.
- When the invalid `gid` is given to the function `getSheetById`, `null` is returned.

#### References:

- [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I solve this problem! 

Comment: @Sehyeon Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.